# Forge Viewer Offline file viewing

Tags: autodesk-forge

Please let me know how to view the Revit file in my local environment in the Forge Viewer without doing any file upload to the cloud.
Also the Link "Prepared a File for the Viewer" it is not working.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately not possible - Forge is a Cloud service only API platform. You need to upload your files to the platform to extract the data, and then visualise it. [Here is a quick and complete tutorial](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/).